# How to speed up rendering of very repetitive html

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I have (automatically generated), very repetitive html code.  A large example can be found at https://www.findstat.org/MapsDatabase/Mp00007/Mp00101, a smaller example is https://www.findstat.org/MapsDatabase/Mp00007

The problem is in the box displaying sequences of mathematical objects, such as

```
[[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]] => [1,0,1,1,0,0]
```

It may contain some 1000 lines, which is, unfortunately, necessary.  Sometimes the first few lines are interesting, sometimes the last, sometimes some in the middle.

An important feature of each such line is the following: when you hover with the mouse over an object, a little graphic visualising it is fetched and displayed.  The name of the png is determined by a prefix determining the sort of object, and the object itself.  Eg., the name for the graphic on the left hand side would be

```
/Graphics/api/Cc0017_[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]].png
```

The prefix is the same for every "column" in the table, but

Currently, each line is represented as follows:

```
<div class="data_line">
    <span>
        [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
    <span class="tooltipContainer">
        <img src="/moin_static196/noimage.png" data-src="/Graphics/api/Cc0017_[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]].png" data-mod="cc-dom-rep" alt="generating graphics...">
    </span>
    </span>
    <span class="operator">=&gt;</span>
    <span class="value">
        [1,0,1,0,1,0]
    <span class="tooltipContainer">
        <img src="/moin_static196/noimage.png" data-src="/Graphics/api/Cc0005_[1,0,1,0,1,0].png" data-mod="cc-codom-rep" alt="generating graphics...">
    </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have not written this code, and I am not really an expert in javascript and html.

I am guessing that it would make sense to shorten each line, perhaps by introducing a new class, but I am not sure how.

So in summary, the data is as follows:

- for each column, there is a prefix ("/Graphics/api/Cc0005") and a modifier tag ("cc-codom-rep")
- for each line, there is a sequence of elements ("[[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]", "[1,0,1,1,0,0]")

Comment: you can either use one of already existing virtual rendering data sets tool or creat your own read about it here https://itnext.io/react-virtual-rendering-448f0f1b81ad

Comment: I don't think you can make much difference by shorten these lines.

Comment: @appleapple: that would be interesting to know! Can you substantiate your claim? As a datapoint (I really have no idea whether it matters), the html code for the box https://www.findstat.org/MapsDatabase/Mp00007/Mp00101 has about 17MB.  It consists of about 11200 displayed sequences, so I am using 1.5KB per sequence, which sounds a lot (there is a fair bit of whitespace).  The amount of data transferred over the network is just 341KB, which looks sensible.

Comment: @MartinRubey well, you say *rendering* so I didn't consider the network issue. I don't know what network speed you expected. but at least it can be zipped when transfer.

Comment: As I wrote in the comment above, the network load is just 341KB.  Of course, we only transfer a gzipped json with the data.  The html is generated by a javascript routine on the consumer's computer.  So my question is: does it really make hardly any difference whether the generated html has 17MB or, say, 6MB (I guess that this might be achievable)?

Comment: @MartinRubey sorry, misread your last comment :/

Comment: @MartinRubey anyway, you should profile it yourself. My **guess** is the zipped size would not change a lot, so it would make no difference on network. For browser rendering speed, it takes around **10%** of total time (not including network) to *parse* the html from my last test, so I don't think the text length make much difference either.

Comment: @MartinRubey btw, it seems like I would not receive notification if you don't @ tag me.

Comment: @appleapple: many thanks for the explanation! I have no idea yet how to profile it properly, but I'll check if I can find out.  Maybe the tools provided by the browser do exactly what's needed.